# hide button combobox changed event

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to hide asp:button when combobox selected index changed. I am not getting error message but simply not working this following code. Please let me know. I tried to use debugger and see the markup code. Here is the generated code.

```
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$plh$Manage1$btnForward" value="Forward" id="ctl00_plh_Manage1_btnForward" name="btnForward" style="visibility: hidden" />

    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$plh$Manage1$btnSave" value="Save" id="ctl00_plh_Manage1_btnSave" name="btnSave" />
```

### JQuery

```
function OnClientNameSelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs) {
    var item = eventArgs.get_item();
      debugger;
    var item = eventArgs.get_item();
    if (item.get_text() == "testing1") {

        $("#btnForward").show();
        $("#btnSave").hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#btnSave").show();
        $("#btnForward").hide();
    }

}
```

### HTML

```
     <asp:Button ID="btnForward" name="btnForward" runat="server" Text="Forward"
        CausesValidation="false" Style="visibility: hidden" OnClick="btnForward_Click" />

      <asp:Button ID="btnSave" name="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click"
         ValidationGroup="GrpHotline" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a *server control*, **btnForward** and **btnSave** are not the Id's generated for your buttons, this will be changed by .NET at run time which will generate something like (**ctl00$plh$Manage1$btnForward**). You need to get the client Id as shown below.

```
    function OnClientNameSelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs) {
        var item = eventArgs.get_item();

        var item = eventArgs.get_item();
        if (item.get_text() == "testing1") {
             $('#<%= btnForward.ClientID %>').show();
             $('#<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').hide();
        }
        else
        {
             $('#<%= btnForward.ClientID %>').show();
             $('#<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: My bad i forgot to add the '#' for JQuery. Updated.

Comment: btnSave.hide() is working but btnForward.show() is not working.

Comment: because u have visibility hidden. use display instead. Style="visibility: hidden" replace it with Style="display: none"

Comment: yes I have changed     CssClass="display: none" . It's working now. thanks.

Comment: Since this has worked for you. Would you mark it as answer?